# Jhipster Docker prod build throws “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded” while executing JUnit tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jhipster

I'm creating the prod build for Jhipster application using docker with the following command:

```
./mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild
```

In the application, there is around 2000+ test case which is generated by Jhipster from the entities.
When I run prod build command it went well for around 1500 test case but after that, it throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` for the remaining test case.

The same exception is thrown when I have run prod command on the server as well.

One thing I noted is that When I run the only test case from the IDE it run all the test case normally.

Comment: Have you tried increasing memory of maven surefire plugin?

Comment: Able to resolved by adding the following line in maven build properties

<argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx1024m</argLine>

Comment: Great, how many entities do you have defined?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou 200+ entities